# SELECT selected CHECKBOX and inserted in selected row into DATABASE

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to input my **questionnaire** *answer* into database

I have table like this in database(example):

```
| id | question     | answer |
+----+--------------+--------+
| 11 | have dinner? | 1      |
| 12 | have house?  | 0      |
| 13 | have garden? | NULL   | 
| 14 | bla bla bla? | NULL   | 

// footnote: answer = 0 as no, answer = 1 as yes
```

Question is *how to input my answer* into id 13, 14 etc..? to **database**

if my controller:

```
/* I am using CodeIgniter */

$data['form_action'] = site_url('dcm/index');
$answer = $this->input->post('answer');
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$selected_answer = $answer['id'];
$this->dcm_model->inputAnswer($answer, $id); // <-- for input answer to model
```

my Model:

```
function inputAnswer($answer, $id){         
$sql = ("
UPDATE question
    SET answer = '$answer'
WHERE id = '$id'
"); $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

in view: (*I am still confusing*)

```
<?php  foreach($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<span> <?php echo $row->id . '. ' . $row->question; ?> </span>
<span> <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="answer" /> </span>
<input type="submit" value="submit answer"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you want to update the data in your database? Try this:

In View:

```
<?php  
echo form_open('controller/method');
foreach($query->result() as $row) { ?>
<span> <?php echo $row->id . '. ' . $row->question; ?> </span>
<span> <input type="checkbox" value="<?=$row->id?>" name="answer[]" /> </span>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" value="submit answer"/>
</form>
```

In Controller:

```
<?php
    $this->dcm_model->inputAnswer();
?>
```

In Model:

```
<?php
    function inputAnswer(){
        $data   = array();
        if($this->input->post('answer')){
            $ans    = $this->input->post('answer');
            foreach($ans as $each){
                if(isset($each) && $each != ""){
                    $data['answer'] = '1';
                    $this->db->where('id', $each)->update('questionnaire', $data);
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: I have use this, but it doesn't change anything in my Database table... is it in Controller just that? "$this->dcm_model->inputAnswer();" ??

Answer (score 0):

use `MVC` pattern like this  and use `update_batch`

in controller get the table details

```
   public function my_function(){       

        $id_array = array();

        $results = $this->my_model->get_results();
        foreach($results as $result)
        {
           array_push($id_array,$result['id']);
        }

        if($this->input->post())
        {
             $checked_id_array = array();
             $checked_ans_Arr = $this->input->post('answer'); 

             $update_array = array();

             foreach($checked_ans_Arr as $checked_ans)
             {
                 $update_array['id'] =  $checked_ans;
                 $update_array['answer'] = 1;
                 array_push($checked_id_array,$checked_ans);
             }

             $not_checked_ids = array_diff($checked_id_array,$id_array);

             if(is_array($not_checked_ids) && count($not_checked_ids )>0)
             {
                 foreach($not_checked_ids as $not_checked_id)
                 {
                    $update_array['id'] =  $not_checked_id;
                    $update_array['answer'] = 0;
                 }
             }

             $this->my_model->update_batch_answers($update_array);

             $results = $this->my_model->get_results();
        } 

        $this->load_view('your_view',array('results'=>$results));    

   }
```

in model

```
public function get_results()
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $his->db->from('table');

   $query = $this->db->get();
   return $query->result_array();
}

public function update_batch_answers($update_array)
{
    return $this->db->update_batch('mytable', $update_array, 'id'); 
}
```

in view

```
<?php  foreach($results as $result) { ?>

<span><?php echo $result['question']; ?></span>
<span> <input <?php if($result['answer']){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" name="answer[]" /> </span>

<?php } ?>

<input type="submit" value="submit answer"/>
```